# syntax error, unexpected token ")" Laravel Send Reset Email Link

Tags: php, laravel

Iam trying to send reset-link for email on my website:
using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password`

```
  $response = Password::broker()->sendResetLink( array(
                'email'=>$user->email,
            ));
            if ($response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
                return $this->sendResponse(true, 'Reset link was sent successfully');
            } else {
                return $this->sendError('Reset link not sent - '.$response);
            }
```

i am always facing `ParseError` : **syntax error, unexpected token ")"**
on file : `/vendor/symfony/css-selector/XPath/Extension/NodeExtension.php`
i am running it on local with php version 8.0.3
and on apache server with php version 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downgrade symfony/css-selector to version 4.4.0